# Запрос из Xamarin.Forms к Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, active-directory, azure

Есть ASP.NET Web Api приложение, защищенное Azure AD (просто шаблон web api, и выбрана аутентификация через облако)

В своем Xamarin приложении реализовал получение токена по [этой инструкции](https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/)

Токен есть, теперь пытаюсь получить данные

```
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/values");
    request.Headers.Authorization = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth.AccessToken);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

В response получаю 401 "Unauthorized". Почему?

Comment: тестировали сервис другими клиентами? к примеру Postman.

Comment: @Dev у нас есть angularjs фронтенд, который оттуда без проблем получает данные

Comment: Есть предположение что вы отправляете запрос по небезопасному протоколу http, попробуйте сменить его на https

Comment: @Nikolay по https передаем, по другому токены передавать не рекомендуют, только так

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, проверь, `get` он требует или `post`.
Токен передаю через клиент, а не запрос, может и тебе поможет:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.AccessToken);
```

Comment: DefaultRequestHeaders устанавливает всем request'ам header.authorization. Так что ведет это решение себя точно так же.

Comment: Тогда либо токен не верен. Либо на сервере авторизация сделана не по дефолту. Если  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.AccessToken) или так client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth.AccessToken); не работает и  AccessToken верен и не равен null то проблема на сервере. Так как при авторизации по умолчанию Asp.Net WebApi должно работать. Ни разу не было проблем. Кроме как на сервере.